# Logging to syslog

Tags: logging, syslog, ibm-datapower

I have a syslog target, with rate limit 1000 events/second, for error priority. I have another log target, target type as file, for error priority. The problem I have, there is one field(response payload after encryption) that gets truncated, within syslog. I use xsl:message for logging. The messages logged to the file

It sounds like a configuration change needed for the syslog server. Could anyone please give some guidance, anyone faced a similar issue? Any configuration, present for syslog server to increase the limit for logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to it, found this link useful for syslogd, for supporting longer syslog messages.

[Truncated syslog messages](http://bsdpants.blogspot.com/2010/08/truncated-syslog-messages.html)

The below are the steps for icreasing the message length
As root, follow these simple steps:

```
This is pretty safe, but just in case: cp -p /usr/sbin/syslogd /usr/sbin/syslogd.bak
cd /usr/src/usr.sbin/syslogd/
vi syslogd.c
find this line in that file (line 71 for me):

#define MAXLINE 1024 /* maximum line length */

... and change '1024' to the value you need (maybe 2048 or 4096).
make obj && make depend && make && make install
/etc/rc.d/syslogd restart
```